# Webpack loading global dependencies using entry property in webpack.config

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack, angular-cli

**Some background:** 
1. I'm using an ejected **webpack.config.js** file from **angular-cli**
2. trying to load **jquery.js & bootstrap.js** (the later dependent on the previous)
3. I'm trying to do that using the **"entry"** property in the **webpack.config.js** file.
4. I want the scripts to run globally in the index.html of the project.

**The current situation**
**the webpack.config.js file:**

```
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","scripts","vendor","main"];
...
module.exports = {
....
"entry": {
"main": [
  "./src\\main.ts"
],
"polyfills": [
  "./src\\polyfills.ts"
],
"styles": [
  "./node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css",
  "./src\\styles.css"
],
"scripts":[
  "./node_modules\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.js",
  "./node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\js\\bootstrap.js"
]
},
}
```

**NOTICE!** I have added the "scripts" array for the jquery & bootstrap.
**NOTICE!** Included the "scripts" into the "entryPoints " array.
**The Result**
1. a bundle named **scripts** is created and loaded containing both **jquery &
 bootstrap**
 
2. **bootstrap** won't recognize **jquery** even though checking the browser console for $ returns the JQuery function. I guess this is an async problem of **bootstrap** being loaded before **jquery**. As a result browser gives the following error emitted by bootstrap from the bundle :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

How should I resolve this issue?
Is there a sync way to load scripts using webpack.config & the entry property?
Why isnt there a guide online on how to do this basic configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unaware that webpack finds the *require* statements and loads the wanted script using that declaration & the load-script load-css plugins. also using the copy-webpack-plugin to copy files like assets helps with resources.

example on how we load css:
in app.module:

```
require('../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

and in the webpack.config:

```
module: {
        rules: [...
        // css global which not include in components
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: "raw-loader"
            })
        },
        // css loader and inject into components
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        }
   }
```